# SearchingThrough Table that uses input tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I am trying to search through a table, which works alright without input tags, however I want to keep the input tags inside the table cells. I have tried using `td.firstElementChild.value` but this did not work.... what do I need to fix in order to search through the table?

here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/1fxxzoe7/114/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to include a common className to be us used by all input elements.

You already do this when creating the input controls:

```
input1.className = 'input';
```

Though, I recommend maybe using a more descriptive className, but either will work as long as the className is unique to the input controls on the page:

```
input1.className = 'search-input';
```

You also already have a unique id for each TR (row) element.

```
tr.id = 'row' + rowCount;
```

Add this id as a data- attribute on the input element, like so:

```
input1.setAttribute('data-tr-id', 'row' + rowCount);
```

Now, get the inputs by className and inspect the values:

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('search-input');
inputElements.foreach(function(item, index){
     var value = item.value;
     // use the data-tr-id attribute to find the TR element to hide/show
     var trElementId = item.getAttribute('data-tr-id');
     var trElement = document.getElementById(trElementId);
     // do the value comparison and hide/show as needed
     if (value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr.style.display = '';
     } else {
         tr.style.display = 'none';
     }
});
```

Comment: what am I doing wrong here? updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/1fxxzoe7/122/

Comment: Your search boxes are configured improperly for your task. -> onkeyup="inputElement.forEach('item', [0])" <- this is wrong. Put the forEarch logic in a function block then call that function passing the element or the element's value. function performSearch(element) { var filter = element.value; // search logic ... } onkeyup="performSearch(this);"